# Rule-based labeling moved and overlapped

Tags: qgis, labeling, error

When I move my labels with the move label tool my double rule-based label is overlapping. 
I have tried to change the settings of its position but it is not possible to affect it once its moved.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It seem to me that you are using two rule in order to get a two line label. if that's the case you could use a single label (based on your two field and formated on two line).

Answer (score 2):

When you use the move tool to move a label, changing its position using the label position options inside the properties will not have any effect. This is because the move tool uses x and y coordinates to fix its position based on the x and y coordinates identifies in the attribute table.

Personally, I rarely use the move tool to change label positions, I usually use conditional statements inside the Data Defined Override to control the labels' locations.

[image: example]

Here is an example:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "FieldName" IN ('Name_1','Name_2') THEN 'T'
  WHEN "FieldName" IN ('Name_3','Name_4') THEN 'B'
ELSE 'TSL'
END
```

Where:

- `"FieldName"` is the name of the field that you want to control the position of its labels
- `'Name_1'`, `'Name_2'`, `'Name_3'`, and `'Name_4'` are the labels that you need to change their positions
- `'T'` means top position
- `'B'` means bottom position
- `'TSL'` means top, slightly left position

The above statement says if the name of the labels are `'Name_1'` or `'Name_2'` put them at the top position, and if the name of the labels are `'Name_3'` or `'Name_3'` put them at the bottom position. Other labels put them at the top slightly left position.

There are 12 options to choose from to place your labels as you like, I am just showing a small sample.

If you want to use the above technique, you need to deactivate `Coordinate X and Y` shown in the above image which uses the positions defined in the attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I would suggest the following steps:

1. Duplicate the layer in which labels you want to have displayed - right-click on the layer and choose **Duplicate Layer**
2. In your duplicated layer: **Properties -> Symbology ->** choose **No Symbols** instead of already applied (replicated from the original layer)
3. In both layers set up the rule-based layers which you want to have displayed. Categorize them between these 2 layers. If you have just 2, make one label visible for the first layer and another one for the second one as shown below.

[image]

Now, when you attend to edit labels from the Labelling Panel, they should be editable separately and not overlap anymore.